# Как измерить расстояние между объктами с учетом поворота

Tags: c#, unity3d

На данном рисунке я попытался максимально изложить суть.
Изображение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Черные стрелки - мировые координаты. Соответственно пытаюсь получить расстояние между объектами, а точнее разницу между координатами точки 1 и точки 2 с учетом их поворота.

Answer (score 0):

Случайно не это нужно: **[Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html)** (или **[Vector2.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html)**)?

```
var dist = Vector3.Distance(firstObject.position, secondObject.position);
DebugLog(dist);
```

Comment: Я немного неверно изложился в теме, мне нужно не расстояние, а разница между двумя координатами с учетом их поворота.

Comment: @skDYLAN что значит `с учетом их поворота`?

Comment: посмотрите на картинку, как видите 2 объекта повернуты, их координатные оси не совпадают с осью мировых координат.
Это как если бы на сцене повернули объект и стали изменять его позицию перетаскивая его за одну из стрелок.

Comment: @skDYLAN я не пойму причем тут поворот объектов и расстояние между ними

Comment: Создаем Куб на сцене, поворачиваем его на 45 градусов, дублируем, зажимая синею стрелку, перетаскиваем куб на некоторое расстояние. Мы изменяли положение куба передвигая его по Оси Z, каким образом можно вычислить разницу между координатами 2-х кубов, чтобы определить на какое расстояние по ОСИ Z мы передвинули куб.
https://i.imgur.com/yU5RJB9.png

Comment: Использую аффинные преобразования можно без труда провести такую операцию, но возможно есть штатный метод

Comment: Смотри, transform.Position твоих объектов - это вектор. Разница двух векторов - тоже вектор. У этого вектора есть составляющие x y z. Это нужные тебе длины проекций на соотвествующие оси. А скаляр (magnitude) получившегося вектора - это его длина.

Comment: @AleksandrAkimov для отправки нужному человеку  используется `собачкаНик`

Answer (score 0):

тема 8 класса, нахождение длины отрезка

√ (z1 - z2)² + (x1 - x2)² + (y1 - y2)²

(всё под корнем)

Answer (score -1):

Решение данной задачи заключается в следующем

```
Vector3 vec = obj1.GetComponent<Transform>().InverseTransformDirection(obj2.GetComponent<Transform>().position) - obj1.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
```

Comment: Вектор - это же не расстояние

Comment: `GetComponent` - это очень и очень плохо.